# Set minimum value to the time tag

Tags: html

```
<input type="time" min = "16:00:00" id = "time" name="time"/>
```

So guys above line doesn't work and I don't know why. I have to specify minimum value for the time from php script, but simply when I wanted to test this input tag I recognised that it doesn't work with simple manual data. Plz make an advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the maximum value:

```
<input type="time" min = "16:00:00"  max="20:00:00" id = "time" name="time"/>
```

**min = time**

*The expected lower bound for the element’s value.
A valid partial-time as defined in [RFC 3339].*

*Examples:*

```
23:20:50.52
17:39:57
```

**max = time**

*The expected upper bound for the element’s value.
A valid partial-time as defined in [RFC 3339].*

*Examples:*

```
23:20:50.52
17:39:57
```

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html)

Comment: @Zheka I added some more details to the answer.